# Multiply Pandas series and multileveled column dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a 2 element pandas series and multilevel column dataframe, where the level 0 of that dataframe overlaps with index values of my series:

```
import pandas as pd
s = pd.Series([0.1, 0.5], index=["A", "B"])
s

A    0.1
B    0.5
dtype: float64


df = pd.DataFrame({("A",1):[0,1,2], ("A",2):[3,4,5], ("A",3):[6,7,8],
                   ("B",1):[10,11,12], ("B",2):[13,14,15], ("B",3):[16,17,18]})
df

    A   B
1   2   3   1   2   3
0   0   3   6   10  13  16
1   1   4   7   11  14  17
2   2   5   8   12  15  18
```

I want to multiply value of my series associated with index "A" by each element of the dataframe where the level=0 column value is "A" and similarly for the "B" value. In the end I want a dataframe that is structured in exactly the same way as my df.

I am trying to do it using mul method, however I don't fully get what I want as some of the rows are NaN:

```
df.mul(s.to_frame().T, level=0)

    A   B
1   2   3   1   2   3
0   0.0 0.3 0.6 5.0 6.5 8.0
1   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

Can someone please provide any help with this?

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify your solution with multiple by first level:

```
df = df.mul(s, level=0)
print (df)
     A              B          
     1    2    3    1    2    3
0  0.0  0.3  0.6  5.0  6.5  8.0
1  0.1  0.4  0.7  5.5  7.0  8.5
2  0.2  0.5  0.8  6.0  7.5  9.0
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I must have looked at my code too much yesterday, because I was pretty sure I've gone through all the combinations one can imagine when applying that mul method, but it looks like I omitted the most natural one. Thanks again!